# Is there any method to save leaflet map image as vector image (i.e. SVG)?

Tags: image, extjs, svg, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am working with web-application which uses OSM and leaflet.
I want to save map image with markers, icons, polylines, polygons and other objects to vector image(SVG/ XML with SVG etc.)
I found leaflet-image but not sure it`s suitable for me.
I also use ExtJs and python as server language. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are two official [plugins for exporting/printing](http://leafletjs.com/plugins#printexport) Leaflet maps.

1. `Leaflet.print` uses a Mapfish or GeoServer print module. Mapfish is built on Python so that could probably work for you. (For completeness - Geoserver is built on Java).
2. `Leafet-image` doesn't use any server side tech at all. Just Canvas and CORS.

You won't be able to save the tiles as vector as those are served to you as PNGs. You could recreate it using standard OSM data and a tileserver though. Both plugins will take the tiles and export them as images.

Comment: i found some tools to render svg map from OSM.
If i use that tool will i be able to save map as SVG with leaflet.print or leaflet-image ?